# How can System.Object use sub-classes as its return types?

Tags: .net, inheritance, clr, paradox

It is true in .NET that *all* types inherit from System.Object.

What I find paradoxical, is a few methods on System.Object - namely

- public virtual **string** ToString();
- public virtual **bool** Equals(object objA, object objB);

System.String is inherited from System.Object:

```
[Serializable]
public class String : Object { /*...*/ }
```

System.Boolean is inherited from System.Object:

```
[Serializable]
public struct Boolean : Object { /*....*/ }
```

What is the going on under the covers that allowed the System.Object class to allow sub-classes to be used as return types on its methods? How did this code ever compiled, as there seems to be a circular references. String <-> Object <-> Boolean.

I'm sure I will see statements, on "thats how it is implemented", but I can understand if these return types were "System.Object"'s themselves, and then a sub-class used the implemenations of string, bool and other System.ValueTypes to  declare a *new* base class.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance,

Dominic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's no big deal, a base class can always reference subclasses. For instance, this code is perfectly legal :

```
class A
{
    public B CreateB();
    {
        return new B();
    }
}

class B : A
{
}
```

Note that it *would* be an issue if A and B were defined in separate assemblies, because that would require a circular assembly reference, which is not allowed

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316518/how-did-microsoft-create-assemblies-that-have-circular-references where it is demonstrated that while circular dependencies are blocked by the IDE, they can be done using the command-line compiler (csc.exe).

Answer (score 2):

A circular reference is only an issue across multiple projects, otherwise parent/child relationship wouldn't ever exist on both sides either.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is *not* entirely true that all types inherit from Object. Please see Eric Lippert's [blog entry on this](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the problem of a base-class returning a derived class.

Moreover I dont see circular dependencies since Object.ToString(); returns a String object. The String class derives from object, but so what? If both are in the same assembly, there is no problem.

Comment: It was more a chicken/egg situation, that's what confused me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see a circular dependency in the .NET framework, then look no further than `System.dll`, `System.Xml.dll` and `System.Configuration.dll`:

[image]

How Microsoft created these assemblies is a mystery to me.  Actually, I might post this as [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316518/how-did-microsoft-create-assemblies-that-have-circular-references)...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said you can also derive a class from a base class that uses the deriving class as a generic type parameter.  There are a lot of neat uses for this pattern.

```
public class A<T>
{
}

public class B : A<B>
{
}
```