# Plugin design, having circular dependency issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop

I have an ecomm application in Project#1.

I have a payment gateway implementation in Project#2 that references Project#1.  It references interfaces so that the gateway is implemented to a contract.

Now I need to actually use the implementation from Project#2 in Project#1.

There is a circular dependency so it isnt' working as it is.

What shall I do? Should I break the interfaces into their own project?  That seems like the easiest approach.

The point is that if I need to create another implementation of a gateway, it can easily be incorporated into Project#1.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question in a different way here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052579/circular-dependancies/2052632#2052632

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting interfaces in a separate library is often a good idea. It also ensures that you can vary and deploy concrete implementations independently of each other.

As a general rule of thumb, when I design, I start by putting the interfaces together with their consumers, and I then move them to a separate library if the need arises.

As far as I understand your description, you have consumers in each library, so moving them sounds like the correct approach.

If you find that these interfaces are **sufficiently unrelated**, you may even want to consider putting them in two **different libraries**.

Comment: what would you use as a namespace for just interfaces?

Comment: ah, now I need to reference enums in my interface project sheesh!

Comment: Namespaces: in many cases you could say that the interfaces represent the real model (the rest is just implementation details), so you may want to name it accordingly.

Comment: Enums are code smells anyway. Refactor them to polymorphic types instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You should put the interfaces that the plugins should implement (along with any potential common helper code) in a separate assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, break your interfaces into another project and reference that project from both.  This way, both are dependent upon an abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dupe of your other question, but it at least has more detail.

If Project 2 is a plugin to Project 1, then Project 1 should not have any dependencies on Project 2, under any circumstances.  Period.

Load Project 2's assembly into Project 1 via reflection/MEF/etc.