# How to send data to sql db via fetch JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make my first project with node JS, todo application. I want to save dynamic checkboxes in sql and after refreshing checkboxes should maintain the state. My friend recommended using fetch but I don't understand how to send data to sql db with it.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function NewBox() {
  var div = document.getElementById("checkBoxes");
  var textfield = document.getElementById("textfield").value;

  ////////////////////

  let checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.id = textfield.toString();

  ////////////////////

  let labe = document.createElement("label");
  labe.htmlFor = textfield.toString();
  labe.id = textfield.toString();
  labe.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textfield));

  ////////////////////

  let br = document.createElement("br");
  br.id = textfield.toString();

  ////////////////////

  const elem = document.getElementById(textfield.toString());

  ////////////////////

  div.appendChild(checkbox);
  div.appendChild(labe);
  div.appendChild(br);
  fetch("/checkbox", { method: post }).then((res) => {});

  checkbox.addEventListener("click", () => {
    checkbox.parentNode.removeChild(checkbox);
    labe.parentNode.removeChild(labe);
    br.parentNode.removeChild(br);
  });
  document.getElementById("textfield").value = "";
}
```

js file with fuction

```
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const checkboxes = "checkboxes.db";

let db = new sqlite3.Database(checkboxes, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  } else {
    console.log("ura");
    db.run(
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS checkbox (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT)",
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.message);
        } else {
          console.log("table created");
        }
      }
    );
  }
});
module.exports = db;
```

```
const { callbackify } = require("util");
const db = require("./db.js");

const createitem = (name, callback) => {
  const sql = "INSERT INTO checkbox(name) VALUES(?)";
  db.run(sql, [name], (err) => {
    callback(err, { id: this.lastID });
  });
};

const readitems = (callback) => {
  const sql = "SELECT * FROM checkbox";
  db.all(sql, [], callback);
};

const updateitem = (id, name, callback) => {
  const sql = "UPDATE checkbox SET name=? WHERE id=?";
  db.run(sql, [name, id], callback);
};

const deleteitem = (id, callback) => {
  const sql = "DELETE FROM checkbox WHERE id=?";
  db.run(sql, id, callback);
};

module.exports = { createitem, readitems, updateitem, deleteitem };
```

creating db and fuctions to them

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
  fs.readFile("index.html", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
    } else {
      res.write(data);
    }
    res.end();
  });
});
app.get("/func.js", (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile("func.js", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
    } else {
      res.write(data);
    }
    res.end();
  });
});

const {
  createitem,
  readitems,
  updateitem,
  deleteitem,
} = require("./database_func");
app.use(express.json());
app.get("/checkbox", (req, res) => {
  readitems((err, rows) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err.message);
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(rows);
    }
  });
});
app.post("/checkbox", (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  createitem(name, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err.message);
    } else {
      res.status(201).send("item is added ID" + data.id);
    }
  });
});
app.put("/checkbox/:id", (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  updateitem(req.params.id, name, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err.message);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send("updated");
    }
  });
});
app.delete("/checkbox/:id", (req, res) => {
  updateitem(req.params.id, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err.message);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send("deleted");
    }
  });
});

console.log("200");
app.listen(2000);
```

my server.

I watched tutorials but still don't get it.

Comment: Why are you reading `func.js` as a file? This seems to be a misunderstanding of how importing files work in JavaScript. You would want to execute the file, right? Here, you are just returning its code.

Comment: Yes because its another file. Yes maybe its not totaly right but it still work, and dont forget im a newbie.The real question is how to implement  fentch.

Comment: If you want to import another file, you use import or require https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63427178/understand-the-behavior-of-require-in-nodejs

Comment: If you want to execute server-side code, you don't return it to the client, you actually execute it. For that, you need to import the file and execute the method from it. If you aren't even executing the code, there's no reason to think the fetch will get you anything but the code (which is useless for client-side).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SccSCuHhOw0 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2EqECiTBL8 Have a look at these beginner crash courses, should clear things up for you. As of right now, your question has multiple fundamental problems that can't be salvaged by a straightforward answer on "how to fetch", so I am voting to close it.