# I want to move a square in a circular motion in java processing

Tags: processing, trigonometry, motion

This is a school project so i cannot use a lot of functions like translate or rotate. I have to use basic trigonometry to do this. So I have made a square and I need it to move in a circular motion 360 degrees with one of it's point constant and not moving.

```
               float rotX,rotY;
               size(500,500);

               fill(#B71143);
               int rectX=width/4;
               int rectY=height/10;
               int rectSize=30;
               angle=angle+0.1;
               //rotX=rectX*cos(angle)-rectY*sin(angle);
               //rotY=rectX*cos(angle)+rectY*sin(angle);

               square(rotX,rotY,rectSize);
```

Comment: The tag "circular-dependency" does not refer to geometry or shapes. Here's a relevant post with informative answers about circular dependencies: [What is a circular dependency and how can I solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042130/what-is-a-circular-dependency-and-how-can-i-solve-it). It's a different programming langauge, but the concept is the same.

Comment: The commented out code almost correctly calculates the coordinates of the rotated square, but in the expression for rotY you need to swap the rectX and rectY.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What you posted does not look like Java code.

Comment: @Mazino Welcome to stackoverflow ! :)  It's great you've posted a snippet of your attempt and made it clear this is for a school project (+1). When you get a chance, check out the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) which should help make most of stackoverflow (as it runs differently compared to forums).

Answer (score 1):

You are so close, at least in terms of the trigonometry part.

In terms of Processing you're only missing `setup()` and `draw()` which will draw a single frame (once you uncomment the assignments of `rotX, rotY` and initialise `angle` to 0)

Here's your code with above notes applied:

```java
float rotX, rotY;
float angle = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);

  fill(#B71143);
}

void draw() {

  int rectX=width/4;
  int rectY=height/10;

  int rectSize=30;
  angle=angle+0.1;
  
  rotX = rectX*cos(angle)-rectY*sin(angle);
  rotY = rectX*cos(angle)+rectY*sin(angle);
  
  
  square(rotX, rotY, rectSize);
}
```

Additionally, if you want to draw from the centre, you can add half the width/height to the square coordinates before rendering (equivalent to translating to centre), and if you want to draw a circle instead of an oval, use the same size for the two radii (named `rectX, rectY`):

```java
float rotX, rotY;
float angle = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);

  fill(#B71143);

  rectMode(CENTER);
}

void draw() {

  int rectX=width/4;
  int rectY=height/4;

  int rectSize=30;
  angle=angle+0.1;
  
  rotX = rectX*cos(angle)-rectY*sin(angle);
  rotY = rectX*cos(angle)+rectY*sin(angle);
  
  // offset to center
  rotX += width / 2;
  rotY += height / 2;
  
  square(rotX, rotY, rectSize);
}
```

Personally I'd simplify the code a bit (though your assignment requirements might differ based on your curriculum).

```java
// initialise angle value
float angle = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);

  fill(#B71143);
}

void draw() {
  // circular motion radius
  int radius = width / 4;
  // define square size
  int rectSize=30;
  // increment the angle (rotating around center)
  angle=angle+0.1;
  // convert polar (angle, radius) to cartesian(x,y) coords
  float x = cos(angle) * radius;
  float y = sin(angle) * radius;
  
  // offset to center
  x += width / 2;
  y += height / 2;
  // render the square at the rotated position
  square(x, y, rectSize);
}
```

(In case you're after another polar to cartesian coordinates conversion formula explanation you can [check out my older answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62893486/what-is-the-math-behind-creation-of-a-star-in-p5js/62895550#62895550) which includes an interactive demo)

Comment: Bro thank you so much for this detailed explanation. But I think I worded the question wrong. What I want to do is make a fan. The two square will move like a fan  with two of it's coordinates constant.

Comment: Happy to hear the explanations are helpful. Indeed, I interpreted circular motion as moving on a circle (hence the alternative to the ellipse path your original code is using). Do you mind posting a new question clarifying the fan motion ? If you could somehow illustrate what you mean that might help. (For example when you say make a fan I don't know if you mean make a static drawing of fan or animate a line with a static pivot at one end and a square at the other, traversing an arc, or something else. I'm not sure what you mean by two of it's coordinates constant.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. If you run my code you will see two squares connected in a single coordinate. I need to make that coordinate constant while the two square move in a circular motion like a fan.

Comment: Can you please post an illustration in a new question ? (I ran your code and I can see one square leaving trails. I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "make that coordinate constant" either.).  Sorry, maybe it's language thing where I might imagine what you imagine when you use the same words :)