# Constant expression depends on itself. Dart circular dependency

Tags: flutter, dart, code-generation, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I am developing a tool that generates dart code and I am facing this runtime error when executing a program having a circular dependency.

```
file.dart:xx:xx: Error: Constant evaluation error:
    this.b = const B(),,
                   ^
file:xx:xx: Context: Constant expression depends on itself.
    this. A = const A(),
```

Here is a simplification of the program I am executing:

```dart
class A {
  final B b;
  const A({
    this.b = const B(),
  });
}

class B {
  final A a;
  const B({
    this.a = const A(),
  });
}
```

As you can see there is a circular dependency between A and B.

I tried dropping the const keyword as:

```dart
class A {
  final B b;
  A({
    this.b = B(),
  });
}

class B {
  final A a;
  B({
    this.a = A(),
  });
}
```

But instead, I am getting a compile time error:

```dart
The default value of an optional parameter must be constant. dart(non_constant_default_value)
```

Do you have an idea how to handle this type of issue? Or is there an equivalent of forwardref in Dart?

## Edit

At the current state of dart, it is not possible to avoid this circular dependency. I ended restricting this case. If the input has a circular dependency, it is normal that the output will have it.

Comment: I am curious *dropping the const keyword* why?

Comment: I tried dropping the const keyword to break the circular dependency. The error is happening because dart is eagerly instantiating B to complete the construction of A, and so on. If I am able to drop const, the process won't be eager fixing the issue (in my opinion).

Comment: I am reading [In this case you need to create a third project "C" which contains the classes that both A and B depend on so they no longer depend on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38042191/10157127), might help you

Comment: Thank you Yeasin, I am checking that !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approaches don't work because when you construct `A()`, it will construct a `B()` which will construct `A()`which will construct `B()`, ad infinitum.  You need to break the infinite recursion loop.

If you want a single instance of `A` and a single instance of `B` to have references to each other, you will need to have one of them pass a reference to itself instead of letting the other constructor create a new instance of the initial type.  You can't pass `this` in an initializer list ([`this` is not yet valid at that point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/)), so it must be done in the constructor body, and the initialized `final` members will need to be `late`.  The constructor body also means that both classes cannot have `const` constructors.

If you want `const` constructors because you want to have `A()` and `B()` as default arguments, [the typical approach is to use `null` as a default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56489812/).

```
class A {
  late final B b;
  A({B? b}) {
    this.b = b ?? B(a: this);
  }
}

class B {
  late final A a;
  B({A? a}) {
    this.a = a ?? A(b: this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using factory constructors?

```
class A {
  final B b;
  
  factory A() => A._(B());
  
  A._(this.b);
}

class B {
  final A a;
  
  factory B() => B._(A());
  
  B._(this.a);
}
```

Comment: This will avoid the compilation error but will result in infinite recursion when run.