# .net seamless c# + f#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, f#

Lets say I have a C# class

```
namespace CSharp;
using FSharp;
class Point
{
    public double[] coords;
    double MyX
    {
        get
        {
            return FSharp.MyX(this);
        }
    }
}
```

And an F# method that would return a coordinate

```
namespace FSharp
open CSharp
let MyX (x : CSharp.Point) = x.coords.item 0
```

And this would be just fine but its circularly referencing because its 2 separate projects (in 1 solution). There would not be a problem if they were treated as if they are the same project, but VS does not let me do that and as far as I'm concerned, you cant use 2 coding languages in 1 project. At least I didnt find a way to do that.

My question is, how to accomplish such a thing?

Comment: Circular dependencies generally suggest poor design. I suggest you rethink your architecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your question is: "How can two projects reference types from each other", the answer is that you can't do that. Circular dependencies between projects are not allowed, see [Circular dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052579/circular-dependencies).

Either extract a common type to a 3rd project that both projects reference, or find a way that one of your two projects don't need to reference this type at all.

Note also that if you were writing this in a single F# project, you'd run into the same problem since F#, unlike C#, [also disallows circular dependencies](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/cyclic-dependencies/) (with some exceptions).

Comment: @TyCobb This is valid C#:
`class A { B foo;}
class B { A foo;}`

A naive translation of this in F# would not compile. This is what I mean by that.

Comment: Ok. Was thinking of actual references (.dll)