# Workaround for Circular Dependencies between API and ClassLibrary Projects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have one API projects with all endpoints and once ClassLibrary which holds all Dtos(model properties). Api projects have reference to ClassLibraray(Common). Actually I want to implement IValidatableObject for my Dtos to validate against the data in DB in classLibraray. For that I need to call Servicees which are available in the API projetcs. I cant refer API to Common(ClassLibraray) projects as its causing circular dependency. I am trying to resolve CD using Interface in newly created classlibraray but no luck. Anyone who can help me here with the solutions would be great. Thank you.

I have tried making Dtos class as partial and one same partial class in API but no luck. Also I am trying to inherit that model in the API with IValidatableObject but that not helping though
PFB how I am trying using inheritance in API sulution

public class DepartmentDto : CreateDepartmentDto, IValidatableObject {

Comment: _"I have one API projects"_ Is it one or more?

Comment: Please View: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052579/circular-dependencies

Comment: I think the classlibrary shouldn't have a reference to the API.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Its one API

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen API have reference to ClassLibraray project. Now I need to have API reference to ClassLibraray to make use of existing services in API solutions.

Comment: @Jazz. We cant refator the classlibaray as  dtos in classlibraray exposed as nuget otherwise I would have moved Dtos to API to resolve it

Comment: Do you need the Dtos in other projects or only in that API?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen. I need the Dtos in ClassLibraray(Common Project). from Here I need to call a service written in the API project. PFB the dtos in Comon Project                       public class DepartmentDto : IValidatableObject {
    
    public Guid SiteGuid { get; init; }

public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {

            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            
                 // Call API.Service.getID(this.SiteGuid)
           
            }
            return results;

Comment: I wouldn't put the code of calling an API in a Dtos library. Dtos are just the descriptions of the data, not how to get the data. The API is responsible for getting the data. You program should have a reference to the API and the Dto, The API has only a reference to the Dtos. Dtos are just "dumb".

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Create an interface for your API and put it in a separate assembly.

```
interface IMyApi
{
    void Foo();
}

class MyApi : IMyApi
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        //etc
    }
}
```

Step 2. Register your API with your IoC container (i.e. [service provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceprovider?source=recommendations&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)) if you have not already done so.

Step 3. Inject your service provider into the validation context when you construct it.

```
var validationContext = new ValidationContext(myDto, myServiceProvider);
```

Step 4. [Retrieve the service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext.getservice?view=net-7.0) within the Validate method.

```
public class DepartmentDto : CreateDepartmentDto, IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var myApi = validationContext.GetService(typeof(IMyApi));
        myApi.Foo();
    
        //etc
```

Comment: Validate method is not getting trigger . API endpoint using CreateDepartmentDto which is in classlibrary and above code is in API project. I am just implementing  the CreateDepartmentDto here along with IValidatableObject otherwise above code looks good.                                                                                                                                        public class DepartmentDtos : CreateDepartmentDto, IValidatableObject {                                        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {

Comment: Sounds like a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431478/how-to-force-mvc-to-validate-ivalidatableobject)