# Does the .NET CLR have a circular dependency?

Tags: .net, clr, circular-dependency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How did Microsoft create assemblies that have circular references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316518/how-did-microsoft-create-assemblies-that-have-circular-references)

I was in the process of putting together a little PowerShell cmdlet that would give me a dependency tree for .NET assemblies, when I discovered something odd:

The .NET 2.0 CLR seems to have a circular dependency: `System` depends on `System.Configuration` and `System.Configuration` depends on `System`. This makes it quite difficult to give a *complete* dependency tree.

Am I off base here? Is there some trickery going on that I don't know about? Why would there be (and, of course, HOW could there have been introduced) this apparent violation of simple and nearly universally-accepted dependency best practices?