# How do I create and use a .NET metadata-only 'Reference Assembly'?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

Since version 3.0, .NET installs a bunch of different 'reference assemblies' under C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft...., to support different profiles (say .NET 3.5 client profile, Silverlight profile). Each of these is a proper .NET assembly that contains only metadata - no IL code - and each assembly is marked with the `ReferenceAssemblyAttribute`. The metadata is restricted to those types and member available under the applicable profile - that's how intellisense shows a restricted set of types and members. The reference assemblies are not used at runtime.

I learnt a bit about it from [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2007/04/12/new-reference-assemblies-location.aspx).

I'd like to create and use such a reference assembly for my library.

1. How do I create a metadata-only assembly - is there some compiler flag or ildasm post-processor?
2. Are there attributes that control which types are exported to different 'profiles'?
3. How does the reference assembly resolution at runtime - if I had the reference assembly present in my application directory instead of the 'real' assembly, and not in the GAC at all, would probing continue and my AssemblyResolve event fire so that I can supply the actual assembly at runtime?

Any ideas or pointers to where I could learn more about this would be greatly appreciated.

*Update:* Looking around a bit, I see the .NET 3.0 'reference assemblies' do seem to have some code, and the [Reference Assembly attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.referenceassemblyattribute.aspx) was only added in .NET 4.0. So the behaviour might have changed a bit with the new runtime.

*Why?* For my Excel-DNA ( http://exceldna.codeplex.com ) add-in library, I create single-file .xll add-in by packing the referenced assemblies into the .xll file as resources. The packed assemblies include the user's add-in code, as well as the Excel-DNA managed library (which might be referenced by the user's assembly).

It sounds rather complicated, but works wonderfully well most of the time - the add-in is a single small file, so no installation of distribution issues. I run into (not unexpected) problems because of different versions - if there is an old version of the Excel-DNA managed library as a file, the runtime will load that instead of the packed one (I never get a chance to interfere with the loading).

I hope to make a reference assembly for my Excel-DNA managed part that users can point to when compiling their add-ins. But if they mistakenly have a version of this assembly at runtime, the runtime should fail to load it, and give me a chance to load the real assembly from resources.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create a reference assembly, you would add this line to your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file:

```
[assembly: ReferenceAssembly]
```

To load others, you can reference them as usual from your VisualStudio project references, or dynamically at runtime using:

[Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2s44xz6.aspx)

or

[Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx)

---

If you have added a reference to a metadata/reference assembly using VisualStudio, then intellisense and building your project will work just fine, however if you try to execute your application against one, you will get an error:

> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.

So the expectation is that at runtime you would substitute in a real assembly that has the same metadata signature.

If you have loaded an assembly dynamically with `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad()` then you can only do all the reflection operations against it (read the types, methods, properties, attributes, etc, but can not dynamically invoke any of them).

---

I am curious as to what your use case is for creating a metadata-only assembly. I've never had to do that before, and would love to know if you have found some interesting use for them...

Comment: making up a **contrived example**: you might create a native image of a .NET assembly using e.g. Mono mkbundle.exe. Now you could still want to allow plugin dlls to access the original assembly's public interface. I'm sure you can make it work this way. If anything it would result in _really_ obfuscated and _large_ assemblies :)

Comment: Adding the ReferenceAssembly attribute does not change the output to a metadata-only assembly like the .NET 4 reference assemblies. I'm trying to find out how those are built. I'll have to try, but after handling the BadImageFormatException, do you think the assembly resolution will call my AssemblyResolve handler? (I'll add details of my use case to the question.)

Comment: I've added some info on why I'm interested. @sehe is not far off the mark! Those packed assemblies are actually small, as I compress them before packing, and CLI assemblies compress pretty nicely. The result is obfuscated only in the 'obscurity' sense - the .NET assemblies are not in your face, so you have to do a bit of work before pointing them at ILSpy. But an obfuscator of that sort would be another good use case.

Answer (score 4):

If you are still interested in this possibility, I've made a fork of the il-repack project based on Mono.Cecil which accepts a "/meta" command line argument to generate a metadata only assembly for the public and protected types.

https://github.com/KarimLUCCIN/il-repack/tree/xna

(I tried it on the full XNA Framework and its working afaik ...)

Comment: Thank you (also for posting back here)! Still interested - I'll have a look when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is new for .NET 4.0.  I'm fairly sure this was done to avoid the nasty versioning problems in the .NET 2.0 service packs.  Best example is the WaitHandle.WaitOne(int) overload, added and documented in SP2.  A popular overload because it avoids having to guess at the proper value for *exitContext" in the WaitOne(int, bool) overload.  Problem is, the program bombs when it is run on a version of 2.0 that's older than SP2.  Not a happy diagnostic either.  Isolating the reference assemblies ensures that this can't happen again.

I *think* those reference assemblies were created by starting from a copy of the compiled assemblies (like it was done in previous versions) and running them through a tool that strips the IL from the assembly.  That tool is however not available to us, nothing in the bin/netfx 4.0 tools Windows 7.1 SDK subdirectory that could do this.  Not exactly a tool that gets used often so it is probably not production quality :)

Comment: Hans, I belive that that tool is actually used more often than you might think. Meta-data only assemblies are also used bootstrapping the Core .Net Framework assemblies, as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316518/z/1316587) to a question about how they compile the .Net Framework assemblies. Of course, there are other changes made via special tools for those assemblies, like the primitatives types having references to the `m_value` member replaced with references to `this`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for the pointer to the other question. So those reference assemblies are 'dehydrated' metadata-only assemblies.

Comment: @Kevin - I don't think so.  It doesn't make sense that the IL has to be stripped in that scenario.  It doesn't get used while building.

Comment: Perhaps that is not the real reason, but stripped assemblies are most certainly used while building the FCL in come cases. I will have more to say about this (and the tool microsoft uses internally) in the form of an answer to this question sometime in the next few days.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I look forward to your insights.

Answer (score 1):

You might have luck with the Cecil Library (from Mono); I think the implementation allows ILMerge functionality, it might just as well write metadata only assemblies.

I have scanned the code base (documentation is sparse), but haven't found any obvious clues yet...

YYMV